# What Django/Python tools should I use to draw objects?

Tags: library, python, django

I want to create a Django app that will use user input to draw objects. The idea is it will look like a very basic furniture planner.

- User provides room dimensions → app displays simple rectangle.
- User inputs location of window → app displays small rectangle at the location inside the room.
- User chooses furniture from the list and writes where should it be placed → another rectangle shows on the graph.

It should be very simple, no bells and whistles. I'm trying to figure out what technologies should I use. I am familiar with Django well enough to stick to it but what tools should I utilize for drawing? For now I'm thinking about matplotlib, what do you think?